# Creating igraph from subset of data table fails

Tags: r, igraph

Below is some code to create a graph. When using the entire data.table object `a`, everything works as expected (though I get warnings about conflicting igraph versions - why?). However, when I uncomment the line `a <- data.table::copy(a[1:3])` then adding the vertices throws an error.

Can someone help me understand how to build a graph without warnings and errors by adapting the code below? I'm using R 3.6.0 and igraph 1.2.4

```
# create data.table.
op_date <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b")
ocpsTT.ocpref <- c("nNBA",  "nNOH",  "nNEE",  "nNBA",  "nNOH",  "nNEE")
a <- data.table(op_date, ocpsTT.ocpref )

# Select subset of rows if needed
#a <- data.table::copy(a[1:3])

# iteratively add stations
add_graphs <- function(x){
  print(x)
  ig <<- ig + igraph::path(x)
}

# make a list of all possible nodes
values <- unique(a[, ocpsTT.ocpref])

# set up empty graph and name vertices
ig <- igraph::make_empty_graph(n = length(unique(unlist(values))),  directed = TRUE) %>%
  igraph::set_vertex_attr("name", value = sort(unique(values)))

# add vertices and plot
a[, .(p = add_graphs(ocpsTT.ocpref)), by=op_date]
plot(ig)
```

Comment: Use something like this: `a[, {add_graphs(ocpsTT.ocpref); .(success = TRUE) }, by=op_date]`. I don't see why you need to collect the return values of `add_graphs` in a data.table.

Comment: Also, functions with side effects are bad. You should probably just use `Reduce`.

Comment: Well, thank you, that works well and as I had expected!  However, when I only select the first two rows of `a` such as `a <- data.table::copy(a[1:2])` then I get three vertices between these two nodes, pointing in both directions, which is wrong. How do I get a single vertex between these two nodes?